# Finding distribution given bivariate normal $f_{xy}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be distributed as bivariate normal random variables with pdf

$$f_{X, Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\biggl(\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2-2\rho(xy)+y^2)\biggr)$$

Find the distribution of $aX+bY+c$.

Would this be done by finding the marginal distributions of both $X$ and $Y$ and then working with those to find the desired distribution?

---

I worked through the problem and used the fact that X varies N(0,1) and Y varies N(0,1).

I then considered $$Var(aX+bY+c)=a^2+b^2+2ab*Cov(X,Y)$$
$$=a^2+b^2+2ab\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y$$
$$=a^2+b^2+2ab\rho$$

Is this it? Then I could say $aX+bY+c$ varies $N(c, a^2+b^2+2ab\rho)$? Seems a little off to me.

Comment: This is an affine transformation of the bivariate distribution. Do you know something about that? Are you familiar with the matrix form of the bivariate normal distribution.

Comment: @Nikolaj1000000 we haven't discussed those in this class unfortunately.

Comment: Do you know the distribution of this bivariate normal distribution?

Comment: @Nikolaj1000000 if by that you mean do I know that $\mu_x, \mu_y=0$ and $\sigma_{x}^2, \sigma_{y}^2=1$, yes. I see that $X ~ N(0,1)$ and $Y ~ N(0,1)$ as well, but because they are not specified to be independent the problem gets more difficult

Comment: If you know the pdf of a bivariate normal distribution, you are right that $\mu_x=\mu_y = 0$ and $\sigma^2_x=\sigma_y^2=1$, and you also see they are correlated with correlation coefficient $\rho$. They are therefore NOT independent and the distribution for $aX+bY+c$ must reflect that.

Comment: Even if you know nothing of matrix form or such things, the normal distribution is completely specified by the mean and variance. Knowing the mean, variance and covariance of the bivariate, you should be able to calculate the distribution of the transformation, since it is 1 dimensional.

Comment: @Nikolaj1000000 I edited my original post above. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is right. There is a more general way to calculate such affine transformations you probably will see later. We have already established that
$$ \begin{pmatrix} X\\ Y \end{pmatrix} \sim N_2\left( 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} , 
\begin{pmatrix} 1& \rho\\ \rho&1 \end{pmatrix}\right) $$
then $aX+bY+c = (a,b)(X,Y)^T + c$ and we find
$$ aX+bY+c \sim N\left( c + (a,b) \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, (a,b) \begin{pmatrix} 1& \rho\\ \rho&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \right)  = N(c, a^2+b^2 +2ab\rho). $$
This is from a general calculation of affine transformation $Y = \eta + BX$, where $X\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ is p-dimensional normal distributed, $B$ is a $k\times p$ matrix and $\eta\in \mathbb{R}^k$. Then
$$Y \sim N_k(\eta+B\mu, B\, \Sigma \,B^T). $$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: Your welcome. Dont forget to mark an answer as accepted.